# Remove or Hide Button Focus outline in ie compatibility mode (jquery impromptu)

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer, impromptu

I am using a jquery modal dialog box plugin named impromptu in my web application. I have a problem with the style of my default button when running in ie compatibility mode.

When my dialog displays with ie compatibility mode disabled my dialog looks like this...

[image]

However when my dialog displays with compatibility mode enabled the default button on my dialog has an ugly border.

[image]

Can someone help me with how I can either remove this ugly border or give me a tip on how I can change the style to look nice.

I primarily support firefox however I have to support ie 7 and above as well.
To do this I have added the following meta tag to my html pages.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7">
```

thanks

Comment: Can you paste the rest of your code for the modal window (html, css)?

Comment: Sure. Here is the link for both the impromptu css (http://pastebin.com/W1qQy71C) and js (http://pastebin.com/Hkhw5H57). And here is the loan calculator example distributed with the impromptu css release where i am having the same problem if I run ie in compatibility mode (http://pastebin.com/VR4YGje9)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the following class

```
.hideFocus{
  hide-focus: expression(this.hideFocus=true);  /* for ie 5+ */
  outline: none;  /* for firefox 1.5 + */
}
```

Comment: Hi Jilykate thanks for your answer. I'm not familiar with the expression syntax. Would you mind having a look at the css link in my comment to patrick and help me on where I should out that. I tried to add that to the contents of div.jqi .jqibuttons button:focus but that doesn't seem to have worked.

Comment: Just some more info. This answer looks to be correct from all of the internet posts out there. I just need to figure out how to change the impromptu code to be able to implement this style. Thanks